# Ionic: Android - Image from Camera is not uploading to server with FileTransfer

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic3

I am trying to pick a image from photo gallary and upload to the server.

I have a PHP script to receive the file and copy to the server location. I have tested this script with Postman. It works perfectly.

I have a provider to upload the image to the PHP script. The code snippet for upload function is below.

```
    upload(imageData) {
    let posturl = APIURL + 'message/upload';

    const fileTransfer: FileTransferObject = this.transfer.create();

    let options1: FileUploadOptions = {
        fileKey: 'file',
        fileName: 'name.jpg',
        headers: {}    
    }

    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
        fileTransfer.upload(imageData, posturl, options1)
        .then((data) => {       
            resolve(data);
        }, (err) => {
            alert(JSON.stringify(err));
            reject(err.message);
        });
    }); 
}
```

TS code for picking the image and calling the provider is:

```
pickimage()
{
    const options: CameraOptions = {
    quality: 100,
    destinationType: this.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
    encodingType: this.camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
    mediaType: this.camera.MediaType.PICTURE,
    sourceType : this.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
    };

    this.camera.getPicture(options).then((imageData) => {
        this.imageURI = imageData;              
    }, (err) => {
        // Handle error
    });
}
```

TS code for picking the image and calling the provider:

```
    this.messageService.upload(this.imageURI).then((result) => {
        this.responseData = result;
        if (this.responseData.status=="success")
        {
                this.mediaurl = this.responseData.mediaurl;
        }
    }, 
    (err) => {
                        alert("Not able to send image");                            
    });
```

The file is not getting uploaded. The alert(JSON.stringify(err)) in the provider returns null.

I am testing this with DevApp.

Any help?

Comment: Are you using livereload option?

Comment: Yes. Using livereload.

Comment: Try without it.

Comment: Still it is not working.